# How to reset aws instance time with UTC time

Tags: amazon-web-services, time

There is a 5 minutes time difference between AWS Ubuntu instance and UTC.

How to **reset** the time with UTC time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon provides the Amazon Time Sync Service, which you can access from your instance. This service uses a fleet of satellite-connected and atomic reference clocks in each region to deliver accurate current time readings of the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) global standard through Network Time Protocol (NTP). The Amazon Time Sync Service automatically smooths any leap seconds that are added to UTC.

The Amazon Time Sync Service is available through NTP at the 169.254.169.123 IP address for any instance running in a VPC

For more details [click here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html)

Comment: Many thanks to you. i got a command to reset it one time.  **sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org** To sync time will run a service asap as per your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

i got a command to reset it one time. **sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org**